# Legend Matrix Plot

Tags: plotting, legending

I have the following problem. I'd like to add a legend to `MatrixPlot`. Each colour should have a legend entry. I used `PlotLegends`, which in principle works. However, if I use more than five colours, this doesn't work anymore.

```
a = RandomInteger[{1, 6}, {50}];
MatrixPlot[{a}, ColorRules ->
                 {1 -> Red, 2 -> Blue, 3 -> Green, 4 -> Gray,5->Yellow,6->Orange}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When `Automatic` fails the same thing can, luckily, be done manually:

```
rules = {1 -> Red, 2 -> Blue, 3 -> Green, 4 -> Gray, 5 -> Yellow, 6 -> Orange};

a = RandomInteger[{1, 6}, {50}];
MatrixPlot[
 {a},
 ColorRules -> rules,
 PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[rules[[All, 2]], rules[[All, 1]]]
 ]
```

[image: Example legends]

A horizontal version (this is an update in response to Bob's new answer) can be achieved thus:

```
PlotLegends -> Placed[
  SwatchLegend[rules[[All, 2]], rules[[All, 1]]],
  Bottom
  ]
```

[image: Horizontal legends]

Answer (score 2):

```
a = RandomInteger[{1, 6}, {50}];

colors = {1 -> Red, 2 -> Blue, 3 -> Green, 4 -> Gray, 5 -> Yellow, 
   6 -> Orange};

Column[{
  MatrixPlot[{a},
   ColorRules -> colors,
   ImageSize -> 400],
  SwatchLegend[
   colors[[All, 2]], 
   colors[[All, 1]],
   LegendLayout -> "Row"]},
 Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]